# tensorflow gradient all nan values-graph convolutional networks

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have designed a single layer neural network:
x=AF
y=x*w
A is matrix(n*n) Graph Adjacency Matrix ,F is matrix(n*2) and w is Wight.
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
def relu(X):
   return np.maximum(0,X)
A1 = np.matrix([
    [0, 0, 1, 0,0,0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0,0,0], 
    [0, 1, 0, 0,1,1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,1,0],
    [0,1,1,0,1,0]],
    dtype=float
)

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A1, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
nodes=list(G.nodes())
print(nodes)
print('edges',len(G.edges()))

UN_G=G.to_undirected()

A=nx.adjacency_matrix(UN_G)
print('un_edges',len(UN_G.edges()))
F = np.matrix([
            [G.in_degree(i), G.out_degree(i)]
            for i in range(A.shape[0])
        ], dtype=float)


I = np.matrix(np.eye(A.shape[0]))
A_prem = A + I


D_hat= np.array(np.sum(A_prem, axis=0))[0]
D_hat = np.matrix(np.diag(D_hat)) 
A_hat=D_hat**-1 * A_prem * D_hat**-1
x=A_hat*F
x=A*F

(x)
```

In the unsupervised loss function: A is sparse matrix

```
def loss_fn(y,A):
  coo = A.tocoo()
  tmp=zip(coo.row, coo.col, coo.data)
  sum = tf.Variable(0.0)
  for i,j,k in tmp:
      sum=sum+k*tf.linalg.norm(y[i]-y[j])
  return (sum)
```

In the weight training phase:

```
epchs=50
w = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((2, 2)), name='w')
eta=0.3
for ephoc in range(epchs):
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    tape.watch(w)
    y = tf.nn.softmax(x @ w)
    loss=loss_fn(y,A)
    print(ephoc,'  ',loss)
  dl_dw = tape.gradient(loss, w)
  w.assign_sub(eta*dl_dw)
```

value of [dl_dw] and loss are nan. What is the problem with my code? Thank you for guiding me

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example does not run; `b` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Now the program is done
Thankful